# shell variable in vars/main.yml?

Tags: ansible

I need to create a variable from a shell command. I can do it in a role file like so:

```
- name: random value
  shell: head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 16
  register: rnd_value
```

But this doesn't work when placed in vars/main.yml:

> ERROR! The vars/main.yml file for role 'test' must contain a
>   dictionary of variables

What is the recommended way to place the instruction to create a variable from a shell command?

Comment: What happens when you `debug var=rnd_value`?  Remember that the variable would be registered to `rnd_value.stdout`.

Comment: It doesn't even run. I updated my question regarding your comment.

Comment: `vars.yml` isn't really the place to run modules from - you should define it within a playbook or a task.

Comment: so vars/main.yml only takes static variables?

Comment: Yep, although they can be overwriten by command line vars

Comment: Same for `defaults/main.yml` as for `vars/main.yml`. They are declarative only, and best used for setting static values, possibly to be overwritten later if needed. `tasks` are better.

Answer (score 0):

Following comments, variables set in vars/main.yml only take static values.

It's the same for defaults/main.yml.

They are declarative only, and best used for setting static values, possibly to be overwritten later if needed.

Tasks are better for the given example.